# Nginx Location docker

Tags: python, docker, nginx

location, which processes the /admin/ path and redirects the request to http://web:8000/admin , How to implement it correctly, I'm new to this topic, thank you!

I didn't understand how to process it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.